# Codeigniter URI_String() conflicts with Social Plugin

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, url, iframe, facebook-social-plugins

Framework: Codeigniter, JQuery

Plugin: http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-plugin-social-share-buttons/getting-started/

Problem: Social Media JQuery Plugin creates Iframes on the page which are causing the URI_String() function to return an incorrect URI (images/tab_share.png rather than the actual page uri)

Solution: possible work around?

Thank you!

The solutions to this problem is to change the tabText: 'share', on the js social plugin initiation script -- Thank you ifaour

Comment: can you provide an example page?

Comment: http://paolienvelope.com/pe/envelope/a8-envelopes

Comment: I can "Like" the page...what's wrong?

Comment: the problem isn't with the social plug in.  The problem is that the social plugin is interfering with the PHP function uri_string() which is returning a uri that represents an image from the social plugin rather than the actual uri of the current page that the user is on

Comment: when a user refreshes a page I have a function in my controller which takes the uri_string() and adds it to a session in order to keep track of pages that a user visits...this isnt much help if every product page shows up as images/tab_share.png which is what is happening because the social plugin is some how interfering

Comment: I just cant see why a resource requested from JS is interfering with a backend script. How about overriding that option `tabText: 'share',`? One thing, I noticed that when loading that "image" `http://paolienvelope.com/pe/envelope/images/tab_share.png` you'll get redirected to your home

Comment: I think it has something to do with the Iframes that the JS loads...the redirect happens because that image is not located on my server in fact the directory doesnt even exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions to this problem is to change the tabText: 'share', on the js social plugin initiation script -- Thank you ifaour